You don't like it? (usual word order) Don't you like it? (question word order)
Could you please help me understand whether I've got to use the usual word order or the question word order in these two situations, and most importantly why. Please, give me some guidance.
A: Hello, mate! Very good to see you.
B: Hi, how are you doing? Nice to see you too.
A: Is that the outfit that you'll be wearing today?
B: It is actually. Yeah. You don't like it? / Don't you like it?

C: Do you like pizza? 
D: No, I don't. 
C: (You're surprised and say:) You don't like pizza? / Don't you like pizza?


To form a question in formal English, you invert the subject and verb. In speech however, you can ask a question using the normal subject verb word order, with a rising question intonation. Both forms are common in speech. There is also a general sense of surprise/disbelief when you don't use the inversion.

You want to say that there's no difference in meaning between "You don't like it?", "Don't you like it?" and "Do you not like it?"?

There is a difference. I've just explained it.

So, the whole difference boils down to formal/informal English? If not, then I would've said that you tried to explain it (not explained).

Yes, kind of.  A question in the inverted word order is more neutral. It's just a question, with no display of emotion or surprise.  A question not inverted is not rude or anything like that, but it is loaded.  It's a bit like saying "I can't believe it, really?".


A question in the inverted word order is more neutral.< Are you sure? I mean, I've long been trying to understand how to ask a genuine negative question in English, but I've been told by native speakers that it's impossible or at least it's not done by adding "not" to the question before the subject, since it shows that it might be a little difficult for the speaker to believe in that = an expression of surprise.


In other words, I'd thought that if I ask "Do you like it?", I want to know if you like it, and if I ask "Do you not like it?", I want to know if you don't like it. But I've been told that the latter doesn't work this way.

Yes I'm sure.  I'm, a native English speaker from the UK. "Do you like it" and "Do you not like it" and "Don't you like it" are all examples of inverted questions. These essentially mean the same.   The use of *not" here as a standalone word only adds a little emphasis. The un-inverted version would be "You don't like it?".  This is essentially a statement, and only becomes a question in speech when using rising question intonation. Don't mix these up.

So, if I want to know, say, if it's legal to smoke in here, I ask "Is it legal to smoke in here?" and if I want to know if it's NOT legal to smoke in here, I ask "Is it not legal to smoke in here?"? And the latter would also be a genuine question (= I have no idea if it's not, and I'm trying to gain information)?

I've said enough on this topic. You already have a good answer from Kate.  It is the correct answer.  If you want to know about the difference between "Do you like it" and "Don't you like it", then ask it as separate question. Stop changing the topic of this question.  You asked about inverted versions and non-inverted versions of questions, and the difference has been explained to you.

I don't think the difference has been explained. You just tried to explain it. I couldn't understand it, sorry.

A question can be asked in the form of a statement (I assume that's what you mean by 'the usual word order'). The speaker's tone of voice indicates that it is intended as a question.
In your two examples, the use of this type of question indicates surprise. A's question "Is that the outfit you'll be wearing today?" hints that they may think that the outfit is unsuitable; B's response implies "Do you mean that you don't like it?"
Since C has already asked "Do you like pizza?", it would be odd to then ask "Don't you like pizza?"


It would be odd to then ask "Don't you like pizza?". But it wouldn't be odd to ask "You don't like pizza?", did I understand correctly? Why?


Because, as I and Billy said, a question in this form implies surprise/disbelief. "Are you really telling me that you don't like pizza?"

If C asked "Don't you like pizza?", D would be puzzled or annoyed. "Why are you asking me again? I've just told you that I don't like it."

yes, but that doesn't explain why D wouldn't be puzzled or annoyed if C asked "You don't like pizza?". See?

I explained that in my previous comment!  C is asking again in a way that indicates surprise. "You really don't like pizza?" "No, because I've never liked cheese."

I'm afraid we're going in circles. You didn't explain it, you tried to explain something I didn't ask for. I'm afraid you didn't understand my question. This question of mine, in this particular thread, was about your answer. You told me that since C has already asked "Do you like pizza?", it would be odd to then ask "Don't you like pizza?" but, I assume that it means that "You don't like pizza? (the usual word order in the question) would not sound odd in that particular context. So I asked why so that I could try to deeper understand the reason for each word order in a negative question.

OK, let's start again. If C has just asked "Do you like it?" it would be unnatural to follow that with "Don't you like it?", but they might respond to an unexpected answer with the question in statement form because that form of question expresses surprise and/or disbelief. OK, D might still be annoyed that C didn't believe them, but they might appreciate that it was surprising and offer some kind of explanation.
